# In java, when using Strings as file Pathnames, what is the difference between '\\' and '\'

Tags: java, file-io

E.g. When I use 
`C:\\a.txt`

It works fine, but when I use
`C:\a.txt`

It does not.

Anyone explain the difference between the two except from saying one works and the other doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\` is a special character used for escaping other special characters. As such, if a single `\` is present it is interpreted as a special character in the string, but since there is nothing to escape, it's considered a "wrong usage".

Therefore, the `\` has to be escaped with a second `\` to give it its literal meaning.

Comment: @user1494256: No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer (or any other answer) as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

A single `\` means an escape sequence which has a specific meaning for the compiler. `\\` basicly escapes the escape sequence. So, if you type `C:\a` the compiler treats `\a` as a escape sequence, something that you did not intend.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 2):

In java the **`\`** symbol is reserved to use with other char to make special symbols, for example,

```
\n is new line
\t is a tab
```

So if you use one **`\`** like in `C:\a.txt` it will think that `\a` is an special char, while using `\\` will be transformed in one `\`

Answer (score 0):

Just a quote to remember : `Backslash is NOT a path separator!`

Answer (score 0):

Its also good use File.separator to get the separator '/' or '\' (if there are others then I dont know about them) necessary for the OS that is running the JVM.